# Обороты с КАК. Где нужно обособить, а где нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, обороты-с-как

Всё ли в этих двух случаях нормально с пунктуацией, как полагаете?

*1. У них ко мне было отношение, как к прокаженному.

2. Эпидемия лихая. Москвичи как к чуме относятся.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пример 1.**  В первом предложении **возможны варианты,** что определяется **структурой** предложения и **расстановкой ударения:**

(1) ***У них ко мне было (такое) отношЕние**, **как к прокажЁнному**.*

При обособлении оборота ударением выделяется (подчеркивается) **существительное**, и этот вариант кажется вполне подходящим для простого предложения.

Примечание. При постановке ударения на слове ***отношЕние*** мы как бы добавляем местоименное указательное слово, так что получается  ***такОе отношение***.

**Поэтому приведенное написание верное, хотя отсутствие запятой также возможно.**

(2) *У них ко мне было отношение **как к прокажЁнному**, вот что меня удивляло.*

В сложном предложении ударение удобнее поставить только  на обороте, в этом случае  он не обособляется и тесно связан со сказуемым (**входит в состав сказуемого в качестве именной части**).

Примечание (**грамматика** оборота)

Сравнить: *Отношение было осторожным, как к прокаженному*. В этом примере оборот находится в однородных отношениях с прилагательным, вместе они составляют именную часть сказуемого.

**Пример 2.** ***Эпидемия лихая. Москвичи как к чУме относятся.***

Здесь обособление невозможно. Это связано со структурой предложения, а также с его **неполной** лексикой (форма *к эпидемии* пропущена). **Ударением** выделяется только оборот, это единственный произносительный вариант.

С точки зрения грамматики оборот тесно **примыкает к сказуемому**(входит в его состав).

Сравнить (два варианта в полном предложении): (1) *Москвичи относятся **к эпидЕмии, как к чумЕ***.(2) *Москвичи относятся к эпидемии **как к чумЕ**, стараются быть осторожными.*

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

*К святому сложилось отношение, **как к иконе**, лик его стал иконописным ликом, перестал быть человеческим.* [Н. А. Бердяев. (1914-1918)]

*У меня к ней отношение, **как к настоящей**; робею ее видеть.* [Н. Н. Пунин. Дневник. 1919-1921 годы (1919-1921)]

*Чтобы быть автором своей жизни, нужно иметь к ней отношение, **как к произведению,** т. е. целому, обладающему смыслом.* [Л. И. Воробьева.«Вопросы психологии», 2004.04.13]

*К ЗАГСу вообще тогда было **отношение как** к пустой и немного смешной формальности.* [И. М. Дьяконов. Книга воспоминаний. Глава девятая (1935-1936) (1995)]

*При этом к человеку формируется **отношение как** к некому биоресурсу или инструменту*... Конфликт цивилизация (миф или реальность) (2006)]

Answer (score 0):

В обоих примерах сравнительная конструкция **входит в состав главных членов предложения**, делая их полноценными в смысловом отношении.

***1. У них ко мне было отношение как к прокажённому.***

Подлежащее ***отношение*** ***как к прокажённому***, сказуемое ***было***. Сравнение внутри подлежащего ***не выделяем***.

***2.Москвичи как к чуме относятся.***

Подлежащее ***москвичи***, сказуемое ***относятся как к чуме***. Запятую внутри сказуемого ***не ставим***.

Comment: Возможно,  такое решение соответствует базовым, а также школьным нормам, где однозначность в большой цене. На ЕГЭ, наверное, так и нужно отвечать, но этот пример явно не из учебника. По примерам из Нацкорпусе,  да и в живой речи мы видим  более свободное произношение и написание. Не надо ставить формальные ограничения там, где  в них нет необходимости. Мы всё-таки не роботы, и наша система правописания позволяет бОльшую свободу, чем  это понимается при чисто формальном подходе к правилам.

Comment: "Запятую внутри сказуемого не ставим"? Не очень понятно.   И разбор неверный: Отношение  - подлежащее, было как к прокаженному - именное сказуемое. (Если не обособлять, конечно). Связку "было" можно убрать.

Comment: Не путайте "было отношение как к прокажённому" и "отношение было как к прокажённому".

Comment: Вот не нравится мне глагол «путать», на мой  «утонченный» слух он звучит высокомерно-пренебрежительно.  Ну да ладно, а что тут по существу? Не путайте… Что именно не путать?  Ага, понятно.  Минуточку, уточню…  Экзистенциальный глагол «быть» отличается от связочного  глагола «быть», который используется  в предложениях характеризации».  Так неужели простая перестановка слов превращает глагол «бытия» в связку для характеризации?  Чудеса, да и только. А «отношение» – это  настолько материальная субстанция, что ее бытие можно как-то зафиксировать?

Answer (score 0):

Всё ли в этих двух случаях нормально с пунктуацией?

1. *У них ко мне было отношение, **как к прокаженному**.*
2. *Эпидемия лихая. Москвичи **как к чуме** относятся.*

Два  самых простых предложения, но они мне очень нравятся, потому что это запись **живой русской речи** –  краткой, яркой и выразительной. И еще потому, что это **очень правильная и точная запись, сделанная по слуху.**  Здесь четко расставлены тонические ударения и паузы, так что никакое исправление не требуется.

Почему я уделяю этому вопросу так много внимания? Дело в том,  что это наглядный пример того, как вообще нужно пользоваться системой русского письма. **Мы так должны писать!**

Нет сомнения, что нужно знать базовую грамматику,  и хорошо ориентироваться в правилах тоже нужно, но вот писать надо – так.  **Свободно!**

Каждый пишет, что он слышит,

Каждый слышит, как он дышит,

Как он дышит, так и пишет…

**А нас учат  –  не слышать!** Нас учат искать подлежащее и сказуемое. А те, кто учат этому, они что-нибудь слышали  **о фразовой структуре предложения?**

При актуальном членении  мы меняем **порядок слов**, а они понимают, для чего это делается. Так обозначается **ритмика речи, расставляются паузы и ударения**, и всё это –  интонация. А иначе это будет не речь человека разумного, а **невнятное бормотание.**

И вот система русского правописания позволяет **всё это чудо отразить на письме**, они-то это понимают? Без интонационно-структурного анализа смысл актуального членения, да и любой смысл вообще никогда не будет ясен. Потому что мы строим предложение **интуитивно, вслушиваясь в эту скрытую ритмику**.

Можно знать все виды сказуемых  и выучить все правила, но это **не поможет сделать правильный вывод**. Вы поставите свою резолюцию  ***написано неверно***  и  объясните весьма туманной фразой – ***сравнение внутри подлежащего не выделяем***.  И будете очень довольны собой. Но это очень серьезная и принципиальная ошибка. При таком подходе живая речь превращается в канцелярское письмо.

**Что может сделать один человек против системы**, потому что "точит ли вода камень" – это еще вопрос! За время работы на форуме я сказала всё, что могла, мне нечего больше добавить. В любом случае, с «просветительством» напрямую пора заканчивать, оно малоэффективно. Что ж, будем искать другие методы…